# UIButton not working on first touch and working on second touch ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using SWRevealViewController to show right side menu. I am not using BarButtons but i have taken a normal button as my app dont have Navigation bar. The problem i am facing is when i touch that button the methods work properly but i cant see the menu bar coming in, and on second touch the side menu comes in. I am not able to figure out the issue. Help Much Appreciated.
'

```
-(IBAction)btnMenuClicked:(id)sender
  {      
   SideMenuTableViewController *sidemenuController = (SideMenuTableViewController *)revealViewController.rightViewController;
   sidemenuController.pitcherArray = [nTimerArray mutableCopy];
   revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width - 50;
    if (revealViewController)
     {
       [self.btnMenu addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(rightRevealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
       [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.tapGestureRecognizer];
     }
    [sidemenuController.tableView reloadData];
   }
```

'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import **`SWRevealViewController`** first

```
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
```

Create a **`property`** for the button as follows...

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *rearButton;
```

And in the **`ViewDidLoad`** method just use this code. It will help you with your problem.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
    if ( revealViewController )
    {

        [self.rearButton addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `tapGestureRecognizer`. It might be work

```
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Answer (score 0):

For me works if I remove the line of `panGestureRecognizer`

Comment: i removed both panGestureRecognizer & tapGestureRecognizer. Still not working. I have to tap twice then it works properly

Comment: Have you tried to put the code in the `viewDidLoad` instead of `btnMenuClicked`. In you code you assigned the action of reveal only when it click this is the reason that works on second tap. Try in the viewDidLoad

Comment: Perfect :) Thax a lot @garanda